# JBoss ESB - How to have multiple input folders for file system provider

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss5.x, esb, jboss-esb

I m using Jboss ESB for my application. I want to implement ESB that  listen the input folders which are dynamically created and when the file comes do the business logic. I have paced a problem at creating the dynamic input folders for esb . 
I'm using following codes for configure the   file system provider.

```
<fs-message-filter
                directory="C:\Project_Root\Projects\FinESB\build\dirs\input"
                input-suffix=".XML"
                work-suffix=".esbWorking"
                post-delete="true"
                post-directory="C:\Project_Root\Projects\FinESB\build\dirs\output"
                post-suffix=".ACK" 
                error-delete="false"
                error-directory="C:\Project_Root\Projects\FinESB\build\dirs\error"
                error-suffix=".IN_ERROR"
            />
```

if you have sn  idea please reply me.

Answer (score 1):

The directory attribute in the configuration file doesn't actually cause a directory to be created in your file system, so it's not "dynamic". JBoss ESB assumes that this directory has already been created. If you attempt to deploy an fs-provider whose directory doesn't exist, you will get a deployment error.

To configure your fs-provider with multiple directories, simply add another `<fs-bus>` to your provider's configuration.

```
    <fs-provider name="MyFSProvider">
        <fs-bus busid="fileChannel1">
            <fs-message-filter directory="C:\fileIngestion\test1"
                error-delete="false" error-directory="C:\fileIngestion\error"
                input-suffix=".txt" post-delete="false" post-directory="C:\fileIngestion\complete" />

        </fs-bus>
        <fs-bus busid="fileChannel2">
            <fs-message-filter directory="C:\fileIngestion\test2"
                error-delete="false" error-directory="C:\fileIngestion\error"
                input-suffix=".txt" post-delete="false" post-directory="C:\fileIngestion\complete" />
        </fs-bus>
    </fs-provider>
```

Comment: Hi Can I point the  <fs-message-filter directory in to parent directory and make the fs-provider listen on child  directories.

Comment: No. The only point at which you configure the directory is in the fs-message-filter. JBoss ESB will poll only that particular directory and not the child directories.

Comment: Thanks,  Can you suggest any way to listen set of folders (number of folders change time to time ) .